# Best port for chats C#

Tags: networking, chat, port

Is there any best port for chat programs? I'm making chat and I don't know what port should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this link useful, has a list of what ports are allocated for certain things as well as commonly used ports:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found that list on web, but there are many ports, to that I can't connect in C# net.sockets. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it matters - just pick one that's not a [well-known port](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers).

Dynamic, private or user-defined  ports should be between 49152 and 65535.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing specific to chat or C# or .NET really. There are some tips in general for picking a TCP/IP port number available on Google, but they are just guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider writing a chat program that uses only outgoing connections on port 80 so that all users will be able to use it.

Any port other than 80 will need some firewall configuration which users may be reluctant to do.

Comment: If I am already using port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) by Apache. Which port should I use then? Is 8080 a port that is always accepted?